# Find if an object is already present in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to create a `HashMap`, that adds objects to a line, if they are not already present in this line. This is how I check it:

```
if (!waiting.containsKey(p)) {
    waiting.put(current, p);
    current++;
}
```

Where `p` is our object, which is stored with an `Integer`. However, when I run this code. It will store the same object several times under different integers, how can this be prevented?

Comment: Use the object as key

Comment: no... why should he do this? an index is ok but he has to use it in containsKey

Comment: Why you want to create a `HashMap` with key as running integers and value as some object ?? I am wondering how you will get back your desired object ?? Ideally `HashMap` is used when there is some relation between you key and value .. To me `ArrayList` looks like a better data structure for you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because you call `containsKey` with the `object` and not the `key`:

parameter must be an `Integer` key

```
Integer lKey = 0;
if(!waiting.containsKey(lKey)){
        waiting.put(current, p);
        current++;
        }
```

if your object has an identifier use this identifier for the map.

```
if(!waiting.containsKey(p.getId())){
            waiting.put(p.getId(), p);
            current++;
            }
```

otherwise use containsValue():

```
if(!waiting.containsValue(p)){
            waiting.put(current, p);
            current++;
            }
```

but then you have to overwrite the equals method.

Comment: Overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()` of a custom object will make this easier. The `p` object's `equals` would handle the `p.getId()` internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object as a key, you can override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to return and compare the `id` of the object.

#### Driver.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<MyObject, Integer> map = new HashMap<MyObject, Integer>();

        map.put(new MyObject(1000L, "One"),   1);
        map.put(new MyObject(1001L, "Two"),   2);
        map.put(new MyObject(1002L, "Three"), 3);

        Long id = 1001L; 

        System.out.println(contains(map, id)); // true
        System.out.println(get(map, id));      // 2
    }

    public static <T, U> boolean contains(Map<T, U> map, T obj) {
        return map.containsKey(obj);
    }

    public static boolean contains(Map<MyObject, Integer> map, Long id) {
        return contains(map, new MyObject(id, ""));
    }

    public static <T, U> U get(Map<T, U> map, T obj) {
        return map.get(obj);
    }

    public static Integer get(Map<MyObject, Integer> map, Long id) {
        return get(map,  new MyObject(id, ""));
    }
}
```

#### MyObject.java

```
public class MyObject {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    protected Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    protected void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MyObject(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject { id : " + id + ", name : " + name + "}";
    }
}
```